# Uploading file with multipart form data and text field

Tags: java, file-upload

I am trying to upload a file along with a text field. Although it is said that I cannot retrieve the value of the text field with `request.getParameter("remarks");`, I imported `commons-fileupload`. Although I cannot seem to figure out what is wrong with my code wherein it has an error in this line `List<FileItem> items = upload.parseRequest(request);` saying `SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [SubmitResult] in context with path [/HIS] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils`

Html:

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <input type="hidden" name="orderid2" id="orderid2">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Remarks:
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="remarks" placeholder="Remarks" autocomplete="off" class="form-control placeholder-no-fix"> <br>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Upload File: &nbsp;
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="file" name="file" id="file" accept="image/png, .txt, application/pdf, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet, application/vnd.ms-excel, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document,application/msword"/> <br>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Servlet:

```
    String rtempfile = File.createTempFile("temp", "1").getParent();
    MultipartRequest multi = new MultipartRequest(request, rtempfile, 15*1024*1024);
    Enumeration files = multi.getFileNames();

    DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
    ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
    List<FileItem> items = upload.parseRequest(request);
    Iterator<FileItem> iter = items.iterator();
    while(iter.hasNext()) {
        FileItem item = iter.next();
        if(item.isFormField()) {
        String name = item.getFieldName();
        String value = item.getString();
            if(name.equals("orderid2"))
                order.setOrderID(Integer.parseInt(value));
            else if(name.equals("remarks"))
                order.setRemarks(value);
        }
    }
    orderDAO.submitResult(order, multi, files);
```

Comment: It seems you have not included Commons IO jar to your project just download and include them. http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/download_io.cgi

Answer (score 0):

```
            MultipartRequest multi = new MultipartRequest(request,appPath,10*1024*1024); // 10MB
            Enumeration params = multi.getParameterNames();
             while (params.hasMoreElements()) 
            {
                paramname = (String) params.nextElement();

                if(paramname.equalsIgnoreCase("cname"))
                {
                    Class=multi.getParameter(paramname);
                }

                if(paramname.equalsIgnoreCase("pno"))
                {
                    phone=multi.getParameter(paramname);
                }
                if(paramname.equalsIgnoreCase("fee"))
                {
                    fee=multi.getParameter(paramname);
                }

                if(paramname.equalsIgnoreCase("fname"))
                {
                    image=multi.getParameter(paramname);
                }

                if(paramname.equalsIgnoreCase("fname1"))
                {
                    image1=multi.getParameter(paramname);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Although the code is appreciated, it should always have an accompanying explanation. This doesn't have to be long, but it is expected.